# Internet Explorer AddOn

Tags: internet-explorer

I Am working now on IE AddOns... my requirement is that whenever i double click on my current webpage in IE the word on which double click is done is stored in selection and also i need to find its Abbreviation from my databse... So Question is As i have read many blogs and posts on Web the IE's extension could be registered in BHO form and also now as stated Window.getSelection or Document.getSelection needs to be used in JS.. so how i can bridge them... Pls do reply with complete understanding of flow and technique to handle the problem.. also the optional solutions are welcomed.... thanx in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking the problem.  You want to create a [Web Accelerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc289775%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not a BHO.  This will save you weeks of typing.

Comment: Jeff---Can i add a Menu item Dynamically in context menu, based on selection by user from XML in web accelerator... Thankz in Advance!

Comment: I don't think so.  Context menu extensions are set before the menu is shown.  You'd have to do a lot of native code hackery to get that to work.

Comment: one more question, is it possible to change the size of the preview window shown as popup?